# How to avoid unwanted crash reporting from third party extensions while using Sentry?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, error-reporting, sentry

I have implemented [Sentry for js](https://getsentry.com/for/javascript/) on my extension.
But i am getting unwanted error reporting from third party extensions which my users have installed in their browser.How should I avoid those kinds of errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can whitelist urls in the configuration step.

https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/tips/

Comment: This whitelisting of urls has reduced the third party errors by great margin but still there are some  .. Can you me what can be the reason for this and how can i cope up with it?

Comment: Not sure I understand, could you clarify? Also, as questions become more specific, it becomes less useful for Stack Overflow's audience. Feel free to write in at support@getsentry.com if you're a customer.

Comment: The white / black URLs properties are now called allow / deny Urls and the up to date docs are here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/guides/serverless-cloud/configuration/filtering/#decluttering-sentry